# See what spawned a process

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, logging

How does one see what spawned a process?

Say there is a process visible in Task Manager and you want to see the history of that process spawning.

I found a mysterious SQL Server VSS Writer running in the background and I don't understand what is spawning it as I have no services for it nor applications that use it (just visual studio and none of my projects are accessing it; and it launches after boot, so it's before visual studio launches).

Comment: Use Process Hacker, Process Explorer and/or Process Monitor.

Comment: is a 3rd party tool the only option?

Comment: If something isn't available in 1st party then one has to go with 3rd party :)

Comment: @Biswapriyo correct, and I'm willing to go there, but I'd like to explore all my options and see if there is something that can be done directly. for example, where do these apps obtain that information? cant i just look there myself?